# Is it possible to construct a dictionary comprehension from a list of unparsed strings without double split?

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Consider the following dictionary comprehension:

```
foo = ['super capital=BLUE', 'super foo=RED']
patternMap = {x.split("=")[0]:x.split("=")[1] for x in foo}
```

It is fairly concise, but I don't like the fact that I need to call `x.split('=')` twice. I tried the following but it just results a syntax error.

```
patternMap = {y[0] : y[1] for y in x.split('=') for x in foo}
```

**Is there a "proper" way to achieve the result in the first two lines without having to call `x.split()` twice or being more verbose?**

Comment: [Probably dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980977/convert-list-of-strings-to-dictionary)? [Better target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739911/how-to-split-a-string-within-a-list-to-create-key-value-pairs-in-python) (although this one explicitly ask for shortest code)

Comment: [Related but not on stackoverflow](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-list-of-key-value-values-to-dictionary-in-Python)

Comment: [Or this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246444/convert-string-to-dict-using-list-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: You can do something inelegant, like `{k:v for s in foo for k,v in (s.split('='),)}`, but you should just use a for-loop, generally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go straight to a `dict` with the tuples like:

#### Code:

```
patternMap = dict(x.split('=') for x in foo)
```

#### Test Code:

```
foo = ['super capital=BLUE', 'super foo=RED']
patternMap = {x.split("=")[0]: x.split("=")[1] for x in foo}
print(patternMap)

patternMap = dict(x.split('=') for x in foo)
print(patternMap)

# or if you really need a longer way
patternMap = {y[0]: y[1] for y in (x.split('=') for x in foo)}
print(patternMap)
```

#### Results:

```
{'super capital': 'BLUE', 'super foo': 'RED'}
{'super capital': 'BLUE', 'super foo': 'RED'}
{'super capital': 'BLUE', 'super foo': 'RED'}
```

Comment: The third way is actually incredibly useful; it allowed me to trim spaces from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's more verbose or not, but here's an alternative without calling `split` twice:

```
patternMap = {x1:x2 for x1, x2 in map(lambda f: f.split('='), foo)}
```