# Split string of key=value into dictionary

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary from a string that have key=value

```
s = "key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3"

print({r.split("=") for r in s})
```

Is it possible using dictionary comprehension? If yes, how?

Comment: I think the solution you're after is `{r.split('=')[0]: r.split('=')[1] for r in s.split()}`. But be aware that this will fail for inputs like: `a=2 b=Jhon Smith c=apple`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246444/convert-string-to-dict-using-list-comprehension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert string to dict using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246444/convert-string-to-dict-using-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map`:

```
>>> s = "key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3"
>>> d = {k: v for k, v in map(lambda i: i.split('='), s.split())}
>>> {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can first split on whitespace, then split on `'='`

```
>>> dict(tuple(i.split('=')) for i in s.split())
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
```